# How to mark desired vertices with python(not select)

Tags: vertices, seams, marker

When I'm working with high poly mesh I would like to have vertices which have less/greatter than 4 edges to be highlighted or marked. There seem to be exists a tool in blender which helps to find target vertices - `Select All by Trait -> Faces by sides` in Edit mode and Vertex selection mode. But the issue is that it is **selecting** vertices and when I do something it will unselect them and I have to start again.

Is it possible to mark desired vertices with Python/manually in Blender? Mark like e.g. Seams are marked.